# Need help to use SiteMap MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitemap

While developing sitemap using MVC 4, I have situation whereby my application has more than 3 parameters to navigate.

Current Situation:
1. Index > Page 1 (With Param A, Param B) > Page 2 (With Param A, Param B, Param C, Param D)

When I have navigate from index to Page 1 to Page 2 there is no problem at all,
but I when navigate back from Page 2 to Page 1, it was causing an error because it lost
ONE PARAMETER (this situation it lost Param B).

Here is my sample code:

At Sitemap Config

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Administration" controller="Administrative" action="Index">
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Maintain Methodology Phases" controller="Common/MethodologyPhase" action="Index" key="MethodologyPhase" />
   </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

At Controller Level, it was looked like (Page 1):

```
[Lib.Authorization(ModuleId = "Admin")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Edit Phase", ParentKey = "MethodologyPhase", PreservedRouteParameters = "id,PhaseCode", Key = "EditPhase")]
public ActionResult EditPhase(int id, string PhaseCode) 
{
       ......
}
```

Controller Page 2, it was looked like this:

```
[Lib.Authorization(ModuleId = "Admin")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Create Sub Phase", ParentKey = "EditPhase", PreservedRouteParameters = "id,PCode,Pdesc,SPCode")]
public ActionResult EditSubPhase(int id, string PCode, string Pdesc, string SPCode)
{
      ....
}
```

Do you have any idea what was wrong in my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MVC Area feature. Sitemap is an ASP.Net feature.In MVC, you can use Area to replace sitemap. While having multiple ares in your project, you can define its own routing and parameters. Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm) on how to use area in MVC. Hope this helps.